# How to use Three.js with ParcelJS bundler. (webpack providePlugin alternative)

Tags: three.js, parceljs

A lot of Three.js stuff assumes a global variable THREE (for example three-bmfont-text) being assigned.

How can I tell Parcel bundler to automatically add an import to these modules, and thus avoid 'THREE is not defined' errors? Since they are external I cannot just manually add an import statement.

For webpack I'd use the providePlugin for that. Works fine, but I cannot find anything similar for Parcel.